# `movevm` command is missing in VBoxManage

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to move a VM to another directory and according to the following link we can use `VBoxManage movevm` command for this purpose:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12470/html/move-vm.html

However, VBoxManage on my machine does not have this command! Unfortunately, I could not find any link online discussing this problem. Do you have any opinion what the problem can be?

P.S. The version of my VBoxManage is version 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the VirtualBox forum topic you created here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=92513

> Post by andyp73 » 3. Apr 2019, 17:59
>   It would appear that "VBoxManage
>   movevm" is a recent addition to VirtualBox mostly likely only
>   available in 6.0.x versions. There has, for a long time, been a
>   [Tutorial: Moving a VM](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55003) which may help if you can't upgrade to the
>   latest VirtualBox version.